# Get site load time on url parameters using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, page-load-time

Something went wrong at load time when visit *domain.com?site=www.google.com*, It seems like the time was taken randomly.

code:

```
<html>
<head><p>Website Checker</p>
<script type='text/javascript'>

           function checkhowlongittakes() {
    weburl = "<?php echo $_GET['site']; ?>";
    getLoadTime(weburl, function(time) {
        document.write('load time for ' + weburl + ' was >' + time + 'ms');
    });
}
function getLoadTime(url, callback) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var start = Date.now();
    req.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if (this.readyState == 4)
            callback(Date.now() - start);
    }
    req.open('GET', url);
    req.send();
}
        </script>
</head>



<body onload="checkhowlongittakes()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question you'd like answered? What do mean by "Something went wrong"? Could you clarify that with a stack trace or log output?

Comment: It can be anything from your PC performance issues to network problems, to alien invasion, to...